# How do I capture past the visible area on the Rigol DS1054Z oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope

I'm using a Rigol scope in single-shot mode to capture a signal but it only captures the amount of signal that is visible on the screen. This results in a lot of zooming out to capture and zooming back in to view detail.
Is there a way to have single-shot just capture until the memory is full instead of until the screen is full?

For example when using serial decode the transaction you might want to capture is much longer than the zoomed in scale where you can actually see the decoding.

Is there a quick way to toggle between being zoomed out to capture, and zooming back in to the left hand side instead of the middle of the capture?

Comment: The screen shows what is in memory. Except when you use the Zoom function (press on horizontal) Why do you need this?

Comment: When you're zoomed in, it captures at a higher resolution, so that one screen still fills up memory.

Comment: For serial decode beyond trivialities or precise timing concerns you might be happier using a cheap CY7C68013A USB-based logic analyzer so you can navigate the capture with a halfway sane UI on a computer.  Or using something like an otherwise-useless Hantek 6022 "scope" as a capture device for *Pulseview* you can even run in analog mode to look at a signal while thresholding the other channel and applying a serial decode.  A PC will do an infinitely better job of software decoding, displaying, and navigating than a bench-form scope's processor or UI.  A scope for signals, a PC is for data.

Comment: With 24Mpts(1 CH), 12Mpts(2 CH)  but only 800 pts to display (800x600) and the X axis  control  and zoom  for us/div, How quick do you want to rotate X resolution?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist is there a way to have a button press toggle between two resolutions?

Comment: I'd like to know too.  The best I can do is zoom out on X, capture then zoom back in to see the detail